# Highly upvoted question that doesn't ask a question

Tags: discussion

I just failed an audit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631761/when-should-i-add-redux-to-a-react-app).  I voted close because the question is not specific - In fact, I don't think the author actually asked a question at all.  He simply links to a tutorial and invites suggestions what to do next.  I feel like both "*Unclear what you're asking*" and "*Primarily opinion based*" would be valid close reasons.  I can only assume the audit went the other way because the question has 15 upvotes and its answers have over 45.

So my question is what did I miss here?  Did my unfamiliarity with React and Redux trip me up?  Is this a situation in which this kind of open-ended question is desirable?

While I always strive to do the right thing on reviews (even to the point of searching meta for similar situations when I'm unsure), I know I will make mistakes, but I always try to learn from them.  I still have the review tab open, and I want to move on to other reviews.  But as of right now I can't in good faith click the blue "I Understand" button.

Comment: Did you look at the title? You should see the question.

Comment: Well, darn.  I guess I missed that.  Even so, I still think the question could be closed for either reason.

Comment: With such highly positive score in quite short time, I guessed it got into HNQ or somewhere where some voters only have upvote privilege. Personally, I can't judge it because of my lack of knowledge in those fields.

Comment: I don't see either close reason myself if I take 5 seconds to not be mislead by the poorly chosen title. Its a basic question asking what the heck Redux's purpose is, and that gets explained quite well. If I were in a really bad mood I'd downvote the question for a severe lack of research, but on most days I'd simply let it be.