# Is the reopen audit 23084722 correct? There isn't even a question there

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I have a question about a reopen challenge that I failed. The question was supposedly closed as opinion based. It is https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/23084722. The audit says I should have reopened this question because there is nothing wrong with it. The audit said:

[image]

There isn't even a question presented within the question itself. It is more a statement about how the `Contravariant` family of typeclasses is pretty useful and impressive? Then it provides a link of bad examples, does NOT ask any specific question, and only relates being "Inspired" by the linked content.

**How is this justified as being a question that should be Reopened?**

And more to the point, why is this not "Opinion Based" that should remain closed? Am I missing something obvious in my reopen evaluation? Or, is this a bug in the audit list of questions?

Comment: It's "correct" in the sense that it has a positive score and so far nobody has voted to close the question - that's generally how audits are chosen.

Comment: Because the majority, especially with small sample sizes, is always correct

Comment: That's helpful, but there have been many, many questions closed recently that also had positive scores and they were closed by someone with the privilege to do it. How do I tell the difference between one of those cases and this test case? Or do I just say "It has a positive score, no close votes, so I should reopen it?" Also, I guess my biggest problem with not reopening was "What was the question?". It really looked like an opinion without a question. So those are OK if "Positive score and no close votes".

Comment: If a review smells fishy (too good to be in the review queue, e.g.: well-formatted, already has answers), click through to view the actual post.

Comment: I think that is the best advice. I do, I toggle between the revised question, the revisions and the duplicates, but I have no specific recall of doing it with this one. (but I must have -- the screenshot is of the question itself) Thanks. It helps, but the "positive score and no close-votes" is digestible.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321654 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373570

Comment: “unclear what you are asking” fits well tooo

Comment: you may speak English, but if you don't speak Haskell you're in no position to pass a judgment on any aspect related to a Haskell question. in particular, it is not opinion based as it asks for specific examples. of what, you wouldn't know, even if you had an impression that you recognize the English words used there -- again, *if* you do not speak Haskell. Most people don't, especially those with 0 (zero) Haskell tag participation like yourself. I myself do not speak PHP and would never be so presumptuous as to pass a judgment on a PHP question that is not prima facie vandalism.

Comment: @window.document apparently it was plenty clear to participants with high reputation score ***in the haskell tag***. Maybe, just maybe, their knowledge of the subject matter was a factor in that.

Comment: related: [Remove Haskell questions from review audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283428/839601) and [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303802/839601)

Comment: @gnat that would be good! of course fixing the SO would be even better, but that is something we [must not speak of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385338/is-the-reopen-audit-23084722-correct-there-isnt-even-a-question-there/385341#comment698871_385339).

Answer (score 13):

In this answer, I will mostly deal with what makes the presence of that question on Stack Overflow reasonable.

The title of the question is "Good examples of not a Contravariant/Contravariant/Divisible/Decidable?". `Contravariant`, `Divisible` and `Decidable` are interfaces that form a hierarchy (every `Decidable` is `Divisible`, and every `Divisible` is a `Contravariant`, but not vice versa). Those interfaces are very general, to the point that someone unacquainted with them might find it difficult to, for instance, grasp how they relate to each other. The question asks for counterexamples that shed light on the differences between them. Those counterexamples are meant to be judged on the basis of whether they are simple and transparent enough to illustrate the differences in a clear way (this criterion, though implicit, is evident to potential answerers). The examples presented in the existing answers do fit the bill.

The question links to "Good examples of Not a Functor/Functor/Applicative/Monad?" because that is a well-known (as of now, 196 score and ~13k views) question with the same format but about a different (yet related) hierarchy of interfaces. The examples in the answers over there are not "bad examples" in the slightest. Rather, they are very effective in capturing the contrasts in the way I have discussed above. (In particular, that other question has a stellar answer by user [pigworker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828361/pigworker) -- a widely known and respected academician expert on the subject matter -- built out of examples that are excellent because they are minimal.)

On a more general note, I believe questions asking for on-site examples of clearly defined things under a sufficiently narrow scope are on-topic. My views about that are expressed in my answers to [*Questions looking for an example*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365723/2751851) and [*Is example (not code) requesting in some situations on-topic?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337094/2751851).

Would it be possible to phrase the question in a way that would make it less of a tricky question should it appear in an audit? Possibly. I'd say, however, that has more to do with the lack of subtlety of the audit system ([as Samuel Liew puts it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385338/is-the-reopen-23084722-challege-correct-there-isnt-even-a-question-there#comment698784_385338), "It's 'correct' in the sense that it has a positive score and so far nobody has voted to close the question") than with the acceptability of the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

> There isn't even a question presented within the question itself.

There actually is:

> But I think it would help to understand this typeclasses better if you can see counterexamples for those typeclasses.

The OP is asking for counterexamples.

The lack of a question mark threw you off. And that means that you didn't look past the punctuation (roughly speaking) -- exactly the thing that an audit tests you on.
Yes, this is not the canonical (or the most effective) way to ask at SO. Whether it's good enough is up to community concensus. And the concensus by the readers of that question (in the form of quite many upvotes for the number of views<sup>1</sup> and a lack of downvotes, close votes and clarification requests) claims that it's good enough. They were likely pleased by the fact that it's concise and well-structured.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>[Average SO question score is less than 1 and keeps falling](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1054823/1302132/questions-per-month-and-average-score) so 12 upvotes for 300 views is A LOT of positive feedback</sub>

Comment: Ok, that's the confusing part. With the years of doctoral education I have with the use of the English language, that doesn't present a question. I see what you are getting at, but that's an iffy question at best.

Comment: A question statement requires a question mark, otherwise it's just a statement.

Comment: A post can be considered useful without being a proper question or being on-topic for that matter. Put simply: upvotes and downvotes have no relation to the question's adherence to the requirements of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TinyGiant I didn't take votes as the sole criterion if you read carefully. It's still strong evidence: [average SO question score is less than 1 and keeps falling](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1054823/1302132/questions-per-month-and-average-score); so 12 upvotes for 300 views is A LOT.

Comment: ah the vaunted community! for me and you this might mean a community of a specific tag users, people with a minimal knowledge of subject matter at least. not so for the vast masses of meta participants sure they are perfectly equipped to pass a judgment on *anything* based on pure superficialities alone. but there's a deeper problem with SO, lurking here. a certain pair of researches in the 1990s made billions by deciding that ***not all votes are created equal***,  but that is an anathema to the SO way of doing things. i.e. "12 votes *from whom??* from the tag experts, mostly (probably)!". +1

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev (to your deleted optimistic comment :) ) this hasn't been [*my* experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376444/so-is-going-to-t-wrong-edits-that-break-posts-get-approved-promptly-how-nic?noredirect=1#comment645524_376444) so far. :) (that one is a *gem*)

Comment: btw the question now has 4 close votes on it. *from whom?* nobody knows.

Comment: I mostly agree with ivan on paper. _However_ this particular question really does need cleaning up to meet my high quality standards!

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the link. That comment thread there was an... interesting read. (By the way, if anyone else is wondering, the suggested edit discussed over there was indeed catastrophic.)

Comment: @duplode my pleasure. :) -- not just suggested, approved! and defended!! vehemently, I might say. :)